# ERROR: Failed to find configuration named in jenkins check the global configuration

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

When i build a pipeline in jenkins its gives the error (ERROR: Failed to find configuration named [nocadmin@192.168.101.87] check the global configuration
)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old, but maybe someone find it useful.

- You need to go to Jenkins (upper left corner),
- "Manage Jenkins" from menu on your left,
- scroll to the bottom and choose "Configure system",
- you have "Publish over ssh", if you don't have something like this, you probably need to install plugin
  [image] here you specify config for ssh - your global configuration.
- In your pipeline you need to use it's name for example:
  configName: 'bap@cech'